# Extraction of Digital Terrain Model Intersections

Tags: raster, intersection, esri-ascii-raster

I have two digital terrain models in ESRI ASCII (.asc) format. Their elevations intersect in multiple places. How can I extract the intersection of these two DTMs as a polyline or polygon shapefile?

Example: I'm after the dotted line in this figure as a polyline.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems like more appropriate to solve with [TINs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tin/fundamentals-of-tin-surfaces.htm/), by the nature of the planes they create.

If you have access to the 3D Analyst extension in ArcGIS, I would follow these how to documents:

1. [Creating a TIN surface from raster data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tin/creating-a-tin-surface-from-raster-data.htm/)
2. [How To: Determine the plane of intersection between two TIN or terrain surfaces](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011762/)

Answer (score 1):

Reclassify both DTMs and give them a value of 1.  Then add the two reclassified DTMs together.  Then convert the resulting summation to polygons.  The polygons with an attribute of 2 represents the intersection.

Comment: Apologies but I think you've misunderstood my question. I'm not after the areas that the DTM coverage overlaps, but the locations at which the two DTMs cut into each other - the locations at which the two DTMs are equal.

Comment: Use the Equal To tool in the Spatial Analyst Tools.  Then convert the result to polygons.

Comment: Hi GBG - thanks! We're a step closer. But there aren't necessarily equal values in the two DTMs. They contain elevations saved to 4dp that will cross over at multiple locations. I'm after a polyline of the dotted line in this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gxWP.png

Comment: I don't understand what 4dp means.  Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry - four decimal places.